# How to check and compare similar folder permissions using vbscript

Tags: windows, file-io, vbscript, filesystems

So I have two similar directories full of user profiles folders(one old and one new) I am trying to see if their permissions for the new directory is the same as the old directory. I would like to write a script to reduce the repetitive task of going through all the folders and compare the old directory with the new directory, I have to ensure and validate that all permissions are the same with each folder.

I am thinking that using a Select Case with users name that range from A to Z to display if some changes need to be made.

Any insight and thoughts would be appreciated....Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To keep two directories in sync, I use [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx). It's easy to use, will keep permissions in sync, and has some nice logging functionality.

Comment: thanks for this. I unfortunately don't have admin permissions on this account so I cant download the software. I am also using windows server 2003 so I dont think Robocop will work.

Comment: Robocopy is included in the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=17657 you can either install the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit (easiest) or if you are not allowed to do that, you can extract the file Robocopy.exe, and run it as a standalone program (see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/30dbIxCXvTQ)

Comment: Ok, thanks I will test this out.  Do you think is more efficient then writing a script?

Comment: Oh yeah, compare executing 1 line: Robocopy c:\x c:\y /mir /sec /LOG:file.log ...That will mirror your two directories so they have the same files, Copy security permissions, and log everything. Plunk it into a scheduled task to run every 15 min, and you have your very own synchronized copy... and Done.... versus writing a custom 100+ line PowerShell script to get a list of directories and files, compare them to the other location, then Get-ACL the permissions, and compare them, and figure out what's changed, apply permissions, and finally log it. Not to mention the hours to debug and test it

Comment: I use Robocopy to keep 10,000,000+ files and 1+ TB of data synchronized between multiple locations every day, and it's fast and reliable. Even if you could write a script to do the same, it would never perform at the same speed that Robocopy can do. Remember: Robocopy stands for "Robust" File copy.

Comment: Beware that some files may need to be excluded from synchronization, though (`ntuser.dat` for instance).